# MSI doesn't run from within C#

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I am trying to run an [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) file from C# using the Proces.Start method. The MSI file is fine, because I can run that normally, but when I try to run the MSI file within some C# code I receive the following error.

> "This installation package could not
>   be opened. Verify that the package
>   exists, and that you can access it, or
>   contact the application vendor to
>   verify that this is a valid windows
>   installer package"

Below is the code that I am using to run the MSI file...

```
Process p = Process.StartApplication.StartupPath  "/Packages/Name.msi");

p.WaitForExit();
```

How can I fix this problem?

---

OK, I got it now. I just changed it to run the setup.exe file that is generated with the MSI file, instead of the running the MSI file...

Answer (score 15):

msi files cannot run on their own. If you double click on them, Windows will start

`msiexec /i PathToYour.msi`

Did you try to do that explicitly?

**Example:** (Courtesy @Webleeuw)

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i PathToYour.msi";
p.Start();
```

Comment: forgive me for being retarded, but how would i do that with the Process.Start?

Comment: See Webleeuw's answer for a complete sample.

Answer (score 9):

Addition to question poster's comment on Benjamin's answer:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i PathToYour.msi";
p.Start();
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It is showing the windows installer box with the instructions for some reason.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. See Dirk Vollmar's solution below, which worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

It is also possible to execute the .msi file directly with the associated application. This happens when you set `UseShellExecute` to `true`:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo() 
{ 
    FileName = @"c:\somepath\mySetup.msi", 
    UseShellExecute = true 
});
```