# System.Process.Start - running msi problem

Tags: vb.net

When i try to run a msi using System.Process.Start("test.msi") in a vb app i get the following error.

The installation package could not be opened. Contact application vendor...

Msi file works fine when double clicked, tried System.Process.Start with text files and exe files and they work fine, problem only with msi

files. Running vista. Also tried xp but no luck

Thanks

Comment: The heart of the problem is that MSI's are not executables. You can double click them to open because all versions of Windows have the MSI utility built-in and it knows to open .msi with the MSI utility

Comment: @Samuel, that's not quite all there is to it.  A `.txt` is not an executable either but you can do `System.Process.Start("file.txt")` and it will work.  I have updated my answer to explain.

Comment: You are 100% correct. Should have researched: "..Therefore, the file name does not need to represent an executable file. It can be of any file type for which the extension has been associated with an application installed on the system." -MSDN

Answer (score 5):

If you have a setup.exe with your msi, run that instead.  Otherwise, use this code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i PathToYour.msi";
p.Start();
```

(from here: [MSI doesn't run from within C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006381/msi-doesnt-run-from-within-c))

The reason for needing to do it this way is that when you do `System.Process.Start("file.txt")` it will work since it is (sort of) calling `notepad.exe %1` which will work for a text file but `msiexec %1` will not work for a msi, since msiexec has a required parameter (Option).

You can test this yourself, by trying msiexec file.msi on the command line - it will give you this helpful little message:

[image: msi without an option]

Comment: nProcess = New System.Diagnostics.Process
                nProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec"
                nProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i c:\test.msi"
                nProcess.Start()

Comment: @umarali1 if you type `msiexec /i test.msi` into your console, does that work?  If not, what is the error message?

Comment: The installation package could not be opened. Contact application vendor

Comment: that probably means there is something wrong with the msi.  you say double clicking on it works? what happens if you right click on it and select install?

Comment: that produces the same error, this happens on all msi files e.g. tried a range, even msi files from microsoft website. any suggestions.

Comment: very strange.  Something more fundamental wrong with the machine then I guess.  I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: @tambo, try `msiexec /passive /package "test.msi"`

Answer (score 0):

To help pinpoint the problem, try running some other .exe from your code, like notepad.exe.

```
System.Process.Start("notepad.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The problem lies on declaring the path of the msi. You need to put double quotes around it.

Instead of

`p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i PathToYour.msi"`

try

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i ""PathToYour.msi"""
```